# When deserializing my XML, I'm getting an error that XML is invalid

Tags: c#, soap, xml-deserialization

I have a following SOAP response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
     <insertResponse xmlns="order">
       <out xmlns="order">
           <actionType xmlns="http://serverurl.com">insert</actionType>
           <orderNumber xmlns="http://serverurl.com">54556100766</orderNumber>   
          <errorMsg xmlns="http://serverurl.com">
             <ns1:Error xmlns:ns1="http://exception.serverurl.com">
                <code xmlns="http://exception.serverurl.com">12345</code>
                <message xmlns="http://exception.serverurl.com">Unable to acquire ID. Record does not exist.</message>
              </ns1:Error>
           </errorMsg>
           <orderID xmlns="http://serverurl.com">0000005555</orderID>
           <region xmlns="http://serverurl.com">Region11</region>
           <successMsg xmlns="http://serverurl.com" xsi:nil="true"/>
       </out>
     </insertResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to deserialize it into a following class:

```
public class insertResponse
{
    public string successMsg { get; set; }
    public errorMsg error { get; set ;}
}

public class errorMsg
{
    List<Error> errorList { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method trying to do just that:

```
private T DeserializeSoapResponse<T>(string soapResponse)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(soapResponse);

    var soapBody = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("soap:Body")[0];
    string innerObject = soapBody.InnerXml;


    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using(StringReader reader = new StringReader(innerObject))
    {
        return (T)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

When executing it, I'm getting the exception with the message "There is an error in XML document (1,2)" on the line with the `return` statement.

What am I missing? And if this is the right approach to the problem?

Comment: Please post proper XML. those `-` signs don't belong here. Or when they are in your data, they are the problem.

Comment: And also your start / end tags don't match.`orderNumber` / `customerNumber` etc.

Comment: There are few problems. First, you're ignoring all namespaces in your target classes. And second, you're ignoring some of the elements - like `out`. Try `Edit |> Paste Special |> Paste XML as Classes` in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
<orderID xmlns="http://serverurl.com">0000005555</orderID> <region xmlns="http://serverurl.com">Region11</region>
```

ur orderID closing tag is missing.